# Converting decimal array to byte array and vice-versa in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, decimal, unsafe

I have the following functions to convert primitive array types to byte array so I can convert it to base64 string and then store it somewhere and vice versa, and I'm stuck now because I have to convert decimal type which is not a primitive type. I realise that decimal is basically a struct so I would be converting struct array to byte array, but I've only seen answers using unsafe code and I would like to avoid that if possible. I use Unity and I'm also limited to .NET 2.0

```
    private static string ConvertArrayToBase64<T>(ICollection<T> array) where T : struct
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsPrimitive) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only primitive types are supported.");

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        var byteArray = new byte[array.Count * size];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array.ToArray(), 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
    }

    private static T[] ConvertBase64ToArray<T>(string base64String) where T : struct
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only primitive types are supported.");

        var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        var array = new T[byteArray.Length / Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, 0, array, 0, byteArray.Length);
        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using `System.IO.BinaryReader` and `System.IO.BinaryWriter`.  These will enable you to read and write primitives to/from another stream, such as a `System.IO.MemoryStream`, which you can then access the binary data and convert to base 64 with `Convert.ToBase64String()`

Comment: Solved it by writing the size of the array as int then looped through the decimal array to write the rest, and when reading this first int represent the size of the returning array.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize and deserialize pretty much any object to bytes, XML, JSON, etc.

```
static byte[] serialize<T>(T t)
{
    var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(ms, t);
        return ms.ToArray();            
    }
}

static object deserialize(byte[] bytes)
{
    var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        return serializer.Deserialize(ms);
}

[Serializable] class arrays { public decimal[] decArray; public int[] intArray; }
```

Sample use

```
arrays a = new arrays();
a.decArray = new decimal[] { 1m, 2m };
a.intArray = new int[] { 3, 4 };

byte[] bytes = serialize(a);


arrays result = deserialize(bytes) as arrays;

Debug.Print($"{string.Join(", ", result.decArray)}\t{string.Join(", ", result.intArray)}");
```